# Complex sort of array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a variable and array of objects e.g:

```
var selectedName = 'fff';

[{
    percentage: Math.round(percentage),
    count: count,
    name: 'bbb',
    index: 11,
},
{
    percentage: Math.round(percentage),
    count: 200,
    name: 'aaa',
    index: 2,
},
{
    percentage: Math.round(percentage),
    count: 400,
    name: 'All',
    index: 7,
},
{
    percentage: Math.round(percentage),
    count: count,
    name: 'fff',
    index: 8,
},
{
    percentage: Math.round(percentage),
    count: count,
    name: 'ccc',
    index: 3,
}],
```

I want to sort these as follows: the object which has the name 'All' should always be first. The next object should be the one with the name that matches `selectedName`, in this case 'fff'. And then the rest of the objects should be ordered by ascending order of their 'index' property.

Is this possible in one [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method?

Comment: `arr.sort(compareFunction)` - Look under the Description heading on that page you linked to for examples of `compareFunction`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do it like so:

```js
var selectedName = 'fff';
var percentage = 23;
var count = 3;

var data=[{percentage:Math.round(percentage),count:count,name:"bbb",index:11},{percentage:Math.round(percentage),count:200,name:"aaa",index:2},{percentage:Math.round(percentage),count:400,name:"All",index:7},{percentage:Math.round(percentage),count:count,name:"fff",index:8},{percentage:Math.round(percentage),count:count,name:"ccc",index:3}];


function sortItems(a, b) {
  if (a.name === 'All') {
    return -1
  }

  if (b.name === 'All') {
    return 1;
  }

  if (a.name === selectedName) {
    return -1
  }

  if (b.name === selectedName) {
    return 1
  }

  return a.index - b.index;

}


console.log(items.sort(sortItems));
```

Comment: Have minified input data and wrapped your code in snippet.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, here an example:

```js
var selectedName = 'fff';
let percentage = 1;
let count = 2;
var data=[{percentage:Math.round(percentage),count:count,name:"bbb",index:11},{percentage:Math.round(percentage),count:200,name:"aaa",index:2},{percentage:Math.round(percentage),count:400,name:"All",index:7},{percentage:Math.round(percentage),count:count,name:"fff",index:8},{percentage:Math.round(percentage),count:count,name:"ccc",index:3}];

arr.sort((i, j) => {
    if (i.name === j.name && (i.name === 'All' || i.name === selectedName)) return 0;

    if (i.name === 'All') return -1;
    if (j.name === 'All') return 1;
    
    if (i.name === selectedName) return -1;
    if (j.name === selectedName) return 1;
    
    if (i.index < j.index) return -1;
    if (i.index > j.index) return 1;
    return 0;
})

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Have minified input data so that emphasis is on your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

#### Idea

- `(a.name !== priorityName)` will yield a boolean value. When you use `-`(minus) operator on them, it is converted to numeric value(true: 1, false: 0).
- So if both are neither of priority, both will yield `1` and output will be `0`, which is falsey in JS.
- Failure of previous expression will call current expression and would loop till last expression

```js
var selectedName = 'fff';
var priorityName = "All";
var percentage = 50.4, count= 0;
var data=[{percentage:Math.round(percentage),count:count,name:"bbb",index:11},{percentage:Math.round(percentage),count:200,name:"aaa",index:2},{percentage:Math.round(percentage),count:400,name:"All",index:7},{percentage:Math.round(percentage),count:count,name:"fff",index:8},{percentage:Math.round(percentage),count:count,name:"ccc",index:3}];
  
data.sort(function(a,b){
  return  (a.name !== priorityName) - (b.name !== priorityName) ||
          (a.name !== selectedName) - (b.name !== selectedName) ||
           a.index - b.index;
})

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helping object holding the priority of each element. In your particular case, the highest priority has `All` value.

So firstly we sort the values with higher priority `(All, 'fff')` and when it's done, we sort the rest by the `index` value.

**Note**: Since we are sorting it by ascending order the priority values have to be negative. If we would sort it by a descending order `(b - a)`, they would be positive.

```js
var arr = [{percentage:Math.round("percentage"),count:"count",name:"bbb",index:11},{percentage:Math.round("percentage"),count:200,name:"aaa",index:2},{percentage:Math.round("percentage"),count:400,name:"All",index:7},{percentage:Math.round("percentage"),count:"count",name:"fff",index:8},{percentage:Math.round("percentage"),count:"count",name:"ccc",index:3}],
    selectedName = 'fff',

result = arr.sort(function(a,b){
  var order = {All: -2, [selectedName]: -1, default: 0};
  return (order[a.name] || order.default) - (order[b.name] || order.default) || a.index - b.index;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Better than mine. +1 Just add some explanation